# Does the order in which dynamic libraries are loaded matter?

Tags: python, ctypes, dylib

I am on OS X and installed the Gtk+3 package with Homebrew.

```
brew install gtk+3
```

I can load the installed libraries in Python with the `ctypes` module.

```
$ python2.6
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:20)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import cdll
>>> cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.dylib')
<CDLL '/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.dylib', handle 7fbd10f1a250 at 10aa33210>
>>> cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib')
<CDLL '/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib', handle 7fbd10f0ffb0 at 10aa22dd0>
>>> ^D
```

So far so good. One thing that is bothering me is that if I try to load
the same two libraries above, but in a different order, it throws a **Symbol not found** exception.

```
$ python2.6
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:20)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import cdll
>>> cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib')
<CDLL '/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib', handle 7fad13d00d60 at 10a688210>
>>> cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.dylib')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 423, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 345, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: _g_free
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.dylib
>>> ^D
```

So, loading `atk` first, and then `glib`, works. The other way around does not. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Yep, C libraries are order-dependent, with the dependencies later in the sequence than the dependers.  In C with (say) libs A B and C, if some symbol used in A that was supposed to be found in C gets masked by some like-named interloper in B first.  And ordering them as B C A breaks.  Here, you have the latter case, where libatk is A, the symbol is _g_free, and glib *definitely* needs to be loaded later with the definition of _g_free.  The linker tracks that A's use of _g_free needs to be satisfied by a later library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the same problem shown at the command line level with C. Here, I've made a main.c which calls foo() in foo.so, which calls bar() in bar.so, which calls (for fun) g_free and g_malloc in glib.

```
$ ls -Flas main.o libfoo.so libbar.so | cut -c3-13,34-37,51-
-rwxrwxr-x 2976 libbar.so*    # has bar(), which calls g_free/g_malloc
-rwxrwxr-x 3504 libfoo.so*    # has foo(), which calls bar()   
-rw-rw-r-- 2864 main.o        # has main(), which calls foo()
```

The correct linking command:

```
$ gcc -o main main.o -L. -lfoo -lbar -lglib-2.0
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
worked!
```

Trying to flip the library loading order:

```
$ gcc -o main main.o -L. -lbar -lfoo -lglib-2.0
./libfoo.so: undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which is due to essentially the same issue you're seeing.  The relevant section from "man ld" is this:

> If the archive defines a symbol which was undefined in some object
>   which appeared before the archive on the command line, the linker will
>   include the appropriate file(s) from the archive.  However, an
>   undefined symbol in an object appearing later on the command line will
>   not cause the linker to search the archive again.

So one needs to keep this in mind when loading dynamic libraries even through cdll, it seems.